# Is there a better way to define a preprocessor macro for doing bit manipulation?

Tags: c, embedded

Take macro:

```
GPIOxMODE(gpio,mode,port)    ( GPIO##gpio->MODER   = ((GPIO##gpio->MODER &   ~((uint32_t)GPIO2BITMASK << (port*2))) | (mode << (port * 2))) )
```

Assuming that the reset value of the register is 0xFFFF.FFFF, I want to set a 2 bit width to an arbitrary value. This was written for an STM32
MCU that has 15 pins per port. GPIO2BITMASK is defined as 0x3. Is there a better way for clearing and setting a random 2 bits in anywhere in the 
32-bit wide register.

Valid range for port 0 - 15
Valid range for mode 0 - 3

The method I came up with is to bit shift the mask, invert it, logically AND it with the existing register value, logically OR the result with a bit shifted new value.

I am looking to combine the mask and new value to reduce the number of logical operations bit shift operations. The goal is also keep the process generic enough so that I can use for bit operations of 1,2,3 or 4 bit widths.

Is there a better way?

In the long and sort of it, is there a better way is really an opened question. I am looking specifically for a method that will reduce the number of logical operations and bit shift operations, while being a simple one lined statement.

**The answer is NO**.

You *MUST* do reset/set to ensure that the bit field you are writing to has the desired value.

The answers received can be better (in a matter of opinion/preference/philosophy/practice) in that they aren't necessary a macros and have have parameter checking. Also pit falls of this style have been pointed out in both the comments and responses.

Comment: For starters, I'd enclose `mode` and `port` in parentheses in the macro expansion.

Comment: Are `mode` and `port` typically constants?

Comment: There is already an overuse of parentheticals and having additional parentheses enclosing mode and port would actually decrease readability.

Comment: Mode and port are constants. I'm using enums currently but I don't see why you couldn't use a loop if you wanted to a do a contiguous range of ports. ie ports 9-13 with mode 2.

Comment: Better to decrease readability slightly (only in the macro definition) than to figure out why it breaks for parameters that are expressions with operators.

Answer (score 1):

> The method I came up with is to bit shift the mask, invert it,
>   logically AND it with the existing register value, logically OR the
>   result with a bit shifted new value.

That or an equivalent is the way to do it.

> I am looking to combine the mask and new value to reduce the number of
>   logical operations bit shift operations. The goal is also keep the
>   process generic enough so that I can use for bit operations of 1,2,3
>   or 4 bit widths.
>
> Is there a better way?

You must accomplish two basic objectives:

1. ensure that the bits that should be off in the affected range are in fact off, and
2. ensure that the bits that should be on in the affected range are in fact on.

In the general case, those require two separate operations: a bitwise AND to force bits off, and a bitwise OR (or XOR, if the bits are first cleared) to turn the wanted bits on.  There may be ways to shortcut for specific cases of original and target values, but if you want something general-purpose, as you say, then your options are limited.

Personally, though, I think I would be inclined to build it from multiple pieces, separating the GPIO selection from the actual computation.  At minimum, you can separate out a generic macro for setting a range of bits:

```
#define SETBITS32(x,bits,offset,mask) ((((uint32_t)(x)) & ~(((uint32_t)(mask)) << (offset))) | (((uint32_t)(bits)) << (offset)))

#define GPIOxMODE(gpio,mode,port) (GPIO##gpio->MODER = SETBITS32(GPIO##gpio->MODER, mode, port * 2, GPIO2BITMASK)
```

But do note that there appears to be no good way to avoid such a macro evaluating some of its arguments more than once.  It might therefore be safer to write `SETBITS32` as a function instead.  The compiler will probably inline such a function in any case, but you can maximize the likelihood of that by declaring it `static` and `inline`:

```
static inline uint32_t SETBITS32(uint32_t x, uint32_t bits, unsigned offset, uint32_t mask) {
    return x & ~(mask << offset) | (bits << offset);
}
```

That's easier to read, too, though it, like the macro, does assume that `bits` has no set bits outside the mask region.

Of course there are other, similar formulations.  For instance, if you do not need to support discontinuous bit ranges, you might specify a bit count instead of a bit mask.  This alternative does that, protects against the user providing bits outside the specified range, and also has some parameter validation:

```
static inline uint32_t set_bitrange_32(uint32_t x, uint32_t bits, unsigned width,
        unsigned offset) {
    if (width + offset > 32) {
        // error: invalid parameters
        return x;
    } else if (width == 0) {
        return x;
    }
    uint32_t mask = ~(uint32_t)0 >> (32 - width);
    return x & ~(mask << offset) | ((bits & mask) << offset);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It looks as if I have the simplest form of reset/set in my macro and I'm not going to be able to get away from the two bit-shift and the logical AND/OR operations. I suppose parameter verification would be helpful but would add complexity and I'm looking to keep it simple.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of macros should be avoided as a plaque for many reasons:

1. They are not debuggable
2. They are hard to find  error prone

and many other reasons

The same result you can archive using inline functions. The resulting code will be the same effective

```
static inline __attribute__((always_inline)) void GPIOMODE(GPIO_TypeDef *gpio, unsigned mode, unsigned pin)
{
    gpio -> MODER &= ~(GPIO_MODER_MODE0_Msk << (pin * 2));
    gpio -> MODER |= mode << (pin * 2);
}
```

but if you love macros

```
#define GPIOxMODE(gpio,mode,port)    {volatile uint32_t *mdr = &GPIO##gpio->MODER; *mdr &= ~(GPIO_MODER_MODE0_Msk << (port*2)); *mdr |= mode << (port * 2);}
```

> I am looking to combine the mask and new value to reduce the number of
>   logical operations bit shift operations.

you cant. You need to reset and then set the bits.

Comment: I am not hell bent on the macro solution. I'm looking to increase readability but keeping verbosity of the code to a minimum. I would prefer the preprocessor to do whatever calculation is needed prior to having the code run on silicon. I save a few cycles there if I can keep the macro simple enough.

Comment: If the bit-field can be guaranteed to be all 1s then you could invert 'mode' shift it and XOR it with the register value. But if the bit-field is not all 1s then the process breaks.

Comment: If you can guarantee, it is not generic any more. BTW if you reconfigure how can you guarantee anything.  Such a "guaranteed" assumptions lead to guaranteed problems.

Comment: @MadVocoder42 you will not save any clocks here. The code will be identical.

Comment: Either way, you did answer my question..... "You Can't" I was looking for a bit-wise logical answer however, between you and John Bollinger I am doing pretty much what the two of you suggested. Barring any language preferences and nuances.

Comment: @MadVocoder42 FWIW, most modern processors and compilers will collapse the bit shift, mask, rotate, etc. down to a single instruction.  (if the compiler can recognize that's what you're trying to do)  The arm cortex ISA, for example has 'bit field clear' and 'bitfield extract', 'bitfield set', etc.

Comment: Up-voted for the function suggestion. Though it should be noted that one can't really write more readable code than `SOME_REG5 = X | Y;` or possibly `SOMEREG5 = (X << pos_x) | (Y << pos_y);`. C programmers can read this instantly, but they cannot easily read strange macro languages. Adding abstraction layers over simple GPIO is pretty much doomed to fail and make the code worse.